# The number of solutions of the equation $|\cot x|=\cot x +\frac{1}{\sin x}$ where $0<x<2\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$|\tan x| = \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$$
$$|\tan x|=\tan (\frac x2)$$then x can assume only two values $0,2\pi$ (at least that’s what I think). But since it doesn’t fit in the given interval, number of solutions should be zero, but the answer is 2. How should I correct it?

Comment: You surely have another solution when $\frac{\pi}2<x<\pi$. In this case your equation is equivalent to 
$$-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{\cos x + 1}{\sin x}$$
$$\cos x= -\frac12$$
$$x= \frac23\pi.$$

Comment: Also, careful when equating inverses. You get an equation which is not equivalent to the first one. As a matter of fact $0$ and $2\pi$ **are not** solution to the original equation, which is not defined at those points.

Comment: Why would such an anomaly arise. It’s just an inverse right? (I get that solutions are wrong, but why are they so?)

Comment: Does any number have inverse?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, because $\tan 2\pi$ wouldn’t have an inverse value. Thanks!

Comment: Take, as another example $$x^2=x$$ which has two solutions, but one of them makes the two quantities at LHS and RHS equal to $0$. If you equate the inverses you get $$\frac1{x^2}=\frac1x$$ which only has *one* solution...

Comment: It's easier to check $~\text{sgn}(\cot x) = 1 + \frac{1}{\cos x}~$ for $~\cot x\neq 0~$ .

Answer (score 0):

As $\tan x|\ge0,$

If $t=\tan\dfrac x2,t\ge0$

Consequently
$$\dfrac{2t}{|1-t^2|}=t$$

If $t\ne0,$ $$|1-t^2|=2$$

Check if $t^2>1$ and $t^2-1<0$

Comment: If $t=tan x/2$ how is $\frac{2t}{1-t^2}=t$? Shouldn’t it be equal to $tan x $?

Comment: @Aditya, please learn http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: Yeah, so $\frac {2\tan x/2}{1-\tan^2 x/2}=\tan x$ Since you have put $t=\tan x/2$

Comment: @Aditya, Where is the confusion? We are forming a quadratic equation for $t$

Comment: I am just confused on we ended up with $\frac{2t}{1-t^2}=t$. I assumed you used (incorrectly) the double angle formula for tangent, but now I think you meant something else. Please clarify (I didn’t downvote you btw)